# How to get response body in okhttp when code is 401?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 3.2.0 and here is code for building request object:

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse(AppConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE_JSON);
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, requestBody);


    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                                    .scheme("http")
                                    .host("192.168.0.104")
                                    .port(8080)
                                    .addPathSegment("mutterfly-server")
                                    .addPathSegment("j_spring_security_check")
                                    .addQueryParameter("j_username", jsonObject.getString("emailId"))
                                    .addQueryParameter("j_password", jsonObject.getString("password"))
                                    .build();
        
     request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .addHeader(AppConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_LABEL, AppConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE_JSON)
                                    .addHeader(AppConstants.ACCEPT_LABEL, AppConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE_JSON)
                                    .url(url)
                                    .post(body)
                                    .build();
```

And here is how I parse the response:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
   
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

                    String respBody;
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            respBody = response.body().string();
                            Log.i(TAG, respBody);
                            response.body().close();
                            if (AppMethods.checkIfNull(loginParserListener)) {
                                try {
                                    final VUser user = AppMethods.getGsonInstance().fromJson(respBody, VUser.class);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
  
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        
                        switch (response.code()){
                            case 401:
                                String body="HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED";
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the ideal response(from web rest client) when authentication is failed.

```
{"msgDesc":"The username or password you entered is incorrect..","statusCode":401}
```

**EDIT:**

`response.toString()` returns

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://192.168.0.104:8080/mutterfly-server/j_spring_security_check?j_username=s@s.s&j_password=1}
```

`response.body().toString()` returns

```
okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@528ae030
```

I want to fetch the `msgDesc` which is in response body. Is there any method which will return this string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
switch (response.code()){
        case 401:
           JsonObject object=new JsonObject(response.body().string());
           String body=object.getString("msgDesc");
           break;
}
```

Comment: response.toString() returns 
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://192.168.0.104:8080/mutterfly-server/j_spring_security_check?j_username=s@s.s&j_password=1}

Comment: thanks for the reply but i have edited the post with the response check that out

Comment: Just change toString() to string()

Answer (score 7):

It's quite weird but Square, the company behind OkHttp, has chosen to not use 'toString()' but 'string()' as method for getting the body as a String.

So this works;

```
String string = response.body().string();
//convert to JSON and get your value
```

But this doesn't:

```
String string = response.body().toString();
```

Comment: yeah that's the weird thing.

Comment: `getString()` would also be less likely to cause little mistakes. I stared at my code, compared with the sample I was working from, and just couldn't see this. (Lesson to self - avoid one word function names for "getters")

Answer (score -1):

`401` means `permission denied`.

Check if your `token` is valid or `user`/`password` is correct.

Comment: there is no token generated as i am trying to login user. and more over i want to test the case when user enters the wrong credentials so i can notify user with the 'msgDesc'  received from the server..