# okhttp get failure response

Tags: android, okhttp

I've implemented okhttp in my android client for network calls.

When i get a failure response i get the failure code and the text related to the code as a message but i don't get the custom failure response that the server sends me.
In my failure response in the implemented code the message i get is just "Bad Request".

Whereas the same response from the browser is as follows.
[image]

How do i get the error message the server is giving me back?

My code

```
private void executeCall(Request request, final ResponseListener listener) {
        mOKHttpClient.newCall(request)
                     .enqueue(new Callback() {
                         @Override
                         public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {                              
                             postFailure(listener, (String) call.request()
                                                                .tag(),e.toString());
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                             if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                                 String responseString = response.body().string();                                   
                                 postSuccess(listener, (String)call.request().tag(), responseString);
                             }
                             else {                                 
                                 postFailure(listener, (String)call.request().tag(),response.code()+","+response.message());
                             }
                         }
                     });
    }
```

Here's my response in case of failure.
[image]

Comment: It may be possible when your request is fail server sends failure code 400 and therefore it is showing you bad request, so for failure response also you need to set status 200 and message then only it will accept response from server

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will have to catch error response by `body()` because `response.message()` returns HTTP status message.

In the screen shot provided by you:

**Status** is broken down in `OkHttp` like `response.code()` for HTTP status code which is `400` in your case and `response.message()` for HTTP status message which is `Bad Request` in your case.

The body of the response (be it success or failure) is `response.body()`. And if you want to get it as a `String`, then call `response.body().string()`.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
     if(response.isSuccessful()) {
         String responseString = response.body().string();                                   
         postSuccess(listener, (String)call.request().tag(), responseString);
     }
     else {               
        String errorBodyString = response.body().string();                  
        postFailure(listener, (String)call.request().tag(),response.code()+","+errorBodyString);
     }
}
```

As per comments:

Since you want to read `Message` object from the response, try to do like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject (response.body().string());
String messageString = object.getString("Message");
```

Comment: response.body.string() returns something like this okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@528ae030

Comment: no, `response.body` will not give you that. And it clearly looks its memory reference. Inspect again and try calling `response.body().string()`.

Comment: i did returns the same,i figured out why.
I had to access it as a json object,
see updated code
http://pastebin.com/Lp7eBnb2
also 
this SO post helped me figure it out
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36857049/3518278

updated your answer il accept it.

Comment: Okay, so you want to read `Message` Object of the body? Well, in that case, Yes you will have to convert the String response into JSON object to read. You correctly pointed it.

Comment: @ViVekH, check the updated code, that should work. :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to **get (okhttp3.ResponseBody) errorResponse from Retrofit response** do this..

```
                // Retrofit onResponseCall
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

                    if (response.errorBody() != null) {

                        try {
                            Log.e("errorResponse","" + response.errorBody().toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                }
```

Comment: Where should I do this? Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: If you are using Retrofit call for api response, then  this  Overrided method **onResponse** is a part of  `responseCall.enqueue(Call call , Response response)`

Comment: I use Retrofit with RxJava, I apparently don't get a "Call" object there :/

Comment: Check this out: [Retrofit— A simple Android tutorial](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23)

Comment: I have used robospice with okhttp. Now I have migrated okhttp to okhttp3. Shall I use the okhttp3 for the RequestListener and spiceException.

Comment: There is no `string` member function, only `toString`.